# Woocomerce - Counting a specific category on orders per date

Tags: woocommerce, orders

I need some help please. I'm making this function, but it doesn't works so far. I need to count the "Mushrooms" category products on all of orders per a specific date.!! When the ( $cont ) variable is printed.. it shows no data/value.

```
// Search Category products mushrromms on orders  
global $woocommerce; 
$posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'shop_order'));
$cont = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $order_id = $post->ID;
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        $product_id =  $item->get_product_id();    
        $order_date =  $item->get_date_created();  //get_date_created();
            
        if  ( has_term( 'Mushrooms', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
         $cont++;
          // break; 
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having had a look at your code, the $posts is not returning any posts. As a starting point I suggest that as you are looking at WooCommerce orders that you make use of the WooCommerce specify methods for searching the orders.
Here is your code with some suggestions and corrections with comments inline. Hopefully this will help. I have tested and I believe all you need to do now is add the date restriction criteria in the query at the start and it should work for you. I have stuck with your variable names but you may decide to tweak the code to better reflect what is now happening.

```
// Search Category products mushrromms on orders  
//global $woocommerce; 
//$posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'shop_order'));

// as you are searching woocommerce post why not use the designated woocommerce search method
// for reference https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query
$args = array( 
                'limit' => -1,
                'return' => 'ids', // this will return an array of just the ids
                // later you can put your date criteria here
             );
$posts = wc_get_orders( $args );

$cont = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    //$order_id = $post->ID;   // $post is already the ID as we returned ids from the wc_get_orders query
    $order_id = $post; 
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach($items as $item) {          

        $product_id =  $item->get_product_id();    
        $order_date =  $order->get_date_created();  //get_date_created();  *** I think you meant $order not $item
            
        if  ( has_term( 'Mushrooms', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
            $cont++;
          // break; 
        }
    }
}
```

A useful way of debugging this kind of situation, provided you are on a test server is to turn on debugging in the wp-config.php and then add print statements eg if you had added

```
error_log(print_r($posts,true));
```

You would have quickly discovered that it was returning an empty array. Therefore knowing where to start with finding the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your time with the corrections .  Your code works perfectly.!  I'm getting the orders with this specific category. Now I'm trying to see how i can get the date ( get_date_created(); )  from the order.  I'm  putting the $item->get_date_created();  in the code ..but I'm getting an error.

Comment: foreach($items as $item) {          
                $product_id =  $item->get_product_id();    
                $order_date =  $item->get_date_created();  //get_date_created();  
          if  ( has_term( 'Mushrooms', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
                     $cont++;
      //break;
      
                }
            }

Comment: Glad it worked. As I mentioned in my code to get the date created of the order you need to use $order->get_date_created(); not $item->get_date_created();